# How to pass data from Model instance (which has a values from api) and give it to Text() widget

Tags: api, flutter, dart, parameters, flutter-http

How to pass data from Model instance (which has a values from api) and give it to Text() widget?
But without an examples with listview please. I need to just give the values to Text widget.

In the first block, my weather instance has a values, but I don't know how to give this values to my Text widget. I'll be grateful if you help me

**home.dart file:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:weather_mix_app/models/weather_model.dart';
import 'package:weather_mix_app/services/weather.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<WeatherModel> weather = new List<WeatherModel>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupWeather();
  }

  setupWeather() async {
    Weather weatherInstance = Weather();
    await weatherInstance.fetchData();
    weather = weatherInstance.weather;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text('WHAT I NEED TO WRITE...'));
  }
}
```

My weather.dart (fetching data from api)

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:weather_mix_app/models/weather_model.dart';

class Weather {
  List<WeatherModel> weather = [];

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    try {
      Response response = await get(
          'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=3327f40525a4577b7d0a75aea0c7d44f&query=New%20York');

      Map jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      WeatherModel weatherModel = WeatherModel(
          description: jsonData['current']['weather_descriptions'],
          temp: jsonData['current']['temperature'],
          feels_like: jsonData['current']['feelslike'],
          query: jsonData['request']['query']);
      weather.add(weatherModel);
      print(weather);
    } catch (e) {
      print('caught error! $e');
    }
  }
}
```

and my weather_model.dart

```
class WeatherModel {
  dynamic description;
  dynamic temp;
  dynamic feels_like;
  dynamic query;

  WeatherModel({this.description, this.temp, this.feels_like, this.query});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the `List<WeatherModel> weather = [];` from `Weather` in your `home.dart`, by doing `Weather().weather` , since it is a list, if you only want to show the first data you can do it in the `Text(Weather().weather[0].temp)`

Comment: It gives me a RangeError. Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0. Thanks

Comment: it means the list is empty... because the Text widget is already build before the API can fetch the data. I suggest future builder. If you want I can edit the code to show the example.

Comment: Thank you. Do not edit it, I'll dothat. Thanks